# AdRequest "This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope"

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have seen that recently a new warning has appeared in mi project in the following line:

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

The warning is in "new AdRequest.Builder().build();"

This is the warning:

> This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope

I don't understand why this warning is showing, could it be a bug or something like that?

Comment: Did you find the solution finally?

Answer (score 3):

This warning disappeared after updating to version `21.5.0` of the Google Ads SDK.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
```

Comment: Still getting it in 22.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and added

```
@SuppressLint("VisibleForTests")
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

It is NOT a good solution, but it made the warning go away and the adds seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I get this message in the line:

```
if(ArrayUtils.contains(...)){...}
```

for the term 'contains'.

@McFarlane: I have not implemented 'play-services-ads:21.5.0', but 'play-services-location:21.0.1' instead.